# Multiply NumPy ndarray with every element in another binary ndarray of different size

Tags: python, numpy

I have two ndarrays :

```
a = [[30,40],
    [60,90]]

b = [[0,0,1],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,1]]
```

please notice that a shape might be larger but always square array (50,50) , (100,100)
The wanted result is :

```
Result = [[a*0,a*0,a*1],
         [[a*1,a*0,a*1],
         [[a*1,a*1,a*1]]
```

I managed to get the right answer with this code but I think there would be a built in function in numpy that accomplish this task in fast manners

```
    totalrows=[]
    for row in range(b.shape[0]):
        cells=[]

        for column in range(b.shape[1]):
            print row,column
            cells.append(b[row,column]*a)
        totalrows.append(np.concatenate(cells,axis=1))
    return np.concatenate(totalrows,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there's a NumPy built-in [`np.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) for such block-based elementwise multiplication problems. To solve your case, it could be used like so -

```
np.kron(b,a)
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: a
Out[50]: 
array([[30, 40],
       [60, 90]])

In [51]: b
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [52]: np.kron(b,a)
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, 30, 40],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 60, 90],
       [30, 40,  0,  0, 30, 40],
       [60, 90,  0,  0, 60, 90],
       [30, 40, 30, 40, 30, 40],
       [60, 90, 60, 90, 60, 90]])
```

---

**3D array case**

Now, let's say we are working with `a` as a `3D` array `(m,n,p)` and `b` as `(q,r)` and assuming you are looking to perform such a block-wise multiplication iteratively along the last axis of `a`. Thus, the shapes are to be multiplied along the first two axes on the two inputs to get the output array. To achieve such an output, we need to extend the dimension of `b` by introducing a singleton dimension as the last axis. The final output would be of shape `(m*q,n*r,p*1)`. The implementation would be simply -

```
np.kron(b[...,None],a)
```

Shape check -

```
In [161]: a = np.random.randint(0,99,(4,5,2))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(0,99,(6,7))
     ...: 

In [162]: np.kron(b[...,None],a).shape
Out[162]: (24, 35, 2)
```

Comment: I executed the function, with mine. with b.shape =(4,3) , a.shape=(100,100,3)
kron get me this shape :
(100,400,9)
but the desired output shape :
(400,300,3)

Comment: @samer226047 For that just add one axis to `b` and use `kron` : `np.kron(b[...,None],a)`. Hope this works out for you!

Comment: @samer226047 Added explanation on that!